# How to find the curve and axis?

Tags: analytic-geometry

We consider the following one-sheeted hyperboloid:

$y^2-4x^2+4z^2=4$

This is also a surface (or solid) of revolution. So it must be generated by rotating a curve about an axis.

What curve and axis could be those? How can I find them?

Thanks.

Comment: On the plane $y=0$ you have the iperbola $4z^2-4x^2=4$...

Comment: If it is indeed generated by rotation, then for finding the axis, look for *circles* on the surface.

Comment: @Berci I can't find circles. Is there actually any of them on the surface?

Comment: I'm not sure.. I haven't found neither. Maybe it was not generated by simple rotation: after rotation it might have been pushed or stretched in one direction. (For constant $x$'s, we get ellipses..)

Comment: @Berci, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you wanted to find out about

$$  4 x^2 - y^2 + 4 z^2 = 4 $$

This one is a surface of a 1-sheet hyperboloid of revolution because,

if the coefficient of y^2 is 0, you immediately recognize unit circle

$$ x^2 + z^2 = 1 $$

Inspection of coefficients and their sign is important.

It has the y-axis as axis of symmetry.Note the coefficients of $x^2$ and $ z^2 $ are 
same.

Take sections parallel to x-z plane at a distance or height of $ y =y_1 $

$$  x^2 + z^2 = 1 + y_1^2 /4 $$

The right hand side has a radius increasing above 1 whether y1 is > 0 or y1 < 0.

Next, take section $ z=0. $ This gives you

$$  4 x^2 - y^2  = 4 $$ which is the hyperbola which is rotated about y-axis.